# Regex multiple capture groups on same pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, capture, regex-group

Lets say I have a string:

```
12345678
```

I also have the following patterns:

```
/^.*$/
/^[0-9]+$/
```

Both of these patterns match the string. I want to find out that both patterns match the string. I can loop through each pattern and throw in a `preg_match` but this is too slow.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
preg_match_all('/^(?P<pattern1>.*)|(?P<pattern2>[0-9]+)$/', $string, $matches);
```

This however would give me something like:

```
[
    'pattern1' => '12345678',
    'pattern2' => ''
]
```

As you can see, pattern2 comes up empty because pattern 1 has already captured the string.

How would I write my `preg_match_all` regex so that both pattern1 and pattern2 (and any other patterns) have a chance at matching the same string? However, I am not after a regex rule that will return all patterns if only all patterns match. I want it to return all patterns that do match and all patterns that do not.

**edit**

Just to further clarify,

The patterns I have given as examples, are just examples.

In my actual scenario, there will be an unknown number of patterns which match unknown strings.

The reason looping through a foreach is too slow is because I will be looping through dozens of patterns with thousands of strings. I can speed up this part of the code by how many patterns there are if they can be combined effectively into one rule per string.

Comment: What do you mean by "too slow"? What are you using this for?

Comment: Are those the actually patterns you are checking or just a simple example for the question?  If those are the actual patterns then performance will be better by just checking the values of strlen() and is_int() rather than using regex at all.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I am using this as part of a high performance url router. I know FastRoute exists but my solution is already on average 1.5 times faster even when FastRoute is cached. The part I need the patterns for is the only bottleneck left as the foreach loops over the patterns take too much time.

Comment: @CJWurtz The patterns are just simple examples. In reality, the patterns will be defined by the user of the library and there is no restriction on what they can match.

Comment: I see what you want, but I'm afraid this is not going to be possible; it's not what regular expression matching was designed for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following trick:

```
^(?P<pattern1>(?P<pattern2>^[0-9]+$)|.*)$
```

Since pattern2 is inside pattern1 and separated by `|`.. each character is checked for both the matches..

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qZ2vU2/2)

Comment: The problem is that the order matters; if you switch the two patterns and create a string such as `"a12345678"` you will get the wrong matches.

Comment: in case of `"a12345678"` what should the matches be?

Comment: One match should be empty no matter in which order you supply the patterns.

Comment: It's not empty if you swap the patterns, i.e. `^.*$` as the inner pattern and `\d+` as the alternation.

Comment: Yes.. subset should be in the inner block.. thats why i wrote the regex like that.. and why would one swap the patterns? particular question has certain solution.. changing the solution for same question may not work always..

Comment: "I want it to return all patterns that do match and all patterns that do not." - there's no mention which pattern will be the subset of another.

Comment: @Ja͢ck As I understood the question (might be wrong).. User want to match a string for two/multiple patterns simultaneously.. giving all the patterns that have a match and all the pattterns that dont.. and thats exactly what i think i wrote..

Comment: @hwnd i am sorry i dont know what branch reset feature is.. :P

Comment: @hwnd Out of curiosity I ran your suggestion [here](https://eval.in/351341), but couldn't quite get it to work.

Comment: @Ja͢ck, I assume I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @karthikmanchala Thanks for your demo but like @Jack said, the patterns must ONLY match what they can match. In your example,  all patterns until the last one that matches will contain the same values. So `[a-z]+` which has `[0-9]+` nested within will contain `1234` if `[0-9]+` matches `1234`. Also, the two pattern limit does not exist, I only used two patterns as a simple example. They can be `n` number of patterns.